# disable scrolling on specific page

Tags: css, reactjs

Is there any way to disable scroll on one single page? I tried to set `overflow: hidden` on the specific page but that didn't work. I have to set it on the body in `index.css` to make it work but that obviously disable scroll on all pages. So the only way to do it that comes to my mind is to set CSS class conditionally on the body. Is there any way to conditionally set CSS class in index.js based on the value from a redux store or is there any other way?

my index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom'
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import {createStore,applyMiddleware,compose,combineReducers} from "redux";
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import authReducer from './store/reducers/auth'

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
   auth: authReducer
})

const store = createStore(rootReducer,
   composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk)));

const app =(
   <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
         <App/>
      </BrowserRouter>
   </Provider>
)

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
     {app}
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Comment: What should be the condition to set an unscrollable property to a specific page?

Comment: @xKobalt reacts is single page application so if I set `overflow: hidden` on body then all other 'pages' are affected because they use the same body

Comment: @xKobalt So far my app has two pages.. Login and Home... I need to disable scrolling on login when user is not logged in where in redux store I use token property.. so if the token is available then use one class if not other

Comment: Well... can be the following a solution? - Use a variable to get title page, then compare it  and if it represents the login page, than add a control about the session (so if user is logged, then it should show the body without limitations, else it should have the mentioned property added at body)

Comment: Maybe you can add an id to a specific page and write a function that if it find that id it will remove the classname from body element?

Comment: @xKobalt well yes.. that is what I'm trying to do problem is that I think I can only do it in index.js. To do it in index.js I have to get the value I will compare from a global store which is redux. But I'm not sure I can get to redux store from index.js

Comment: Could you do something like if a certain component is rendered, apply position: fixed to the body. Or add a class to the body when the component is rendered and apply styling to that specific class.

Comment: @ThomasAllen it already has been answered and solution is really really simple

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you wanted to set a style on `body`, you can just run the below code on the page, which will disable scrolling.

```
document.body.style.overflow='hidden'
```

Then to re-enable:

```
document.body.style.overflow='auto'
```

Only downside is that is isn't very React-like.

Comment: Nice... that works... Thank you very much.. So no conditions are needed then.. excellent

Answer (score 4):

Simple solution might be to define specific `class` to apply `overflow: hidden` and apply it on `document.body` whenever you want (for example after explicit component mount).

```css
.overflow-hidden {
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

On mount of specific page call:

```js
document.body.classList.add("overflow-hidden");
```

or you can directly assign property

```js
document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
```

Comment: Yes.. thanks... That is what I was looking for.. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap your component in another div, and give that wrapper div the `overflow:hidden;` style, possibly along with a `max-height: 70vh;` to make sure it doesn't go over the end of the page.

```css
div {
  padding: .5rem;
  margin: .5rem
}

.no-scroll-wrapper {
  max-height: 70vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: darkgrey;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.large-inner {
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: grey
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="no-scroll-wrapper">
    wrapper element disables scrolling
    <div class="large-inner">
      Content here, very long div, but you can't see the end of it.
    </div>
  </div>
  </body
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. problem is as I mentioned that react is single page application so the body is shared between all pages. I will have to do some condition to chose the body class or that overflow property when to trigger it because I want to disable scrolling only on one 'page'... I really don't know how to do it in react though

Comment: I am using blazor in .NET as a SPA framework and this worked perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution might be to define a specific class to apply overflow: hidden and apply it on the document. body whenever you want and remove the class when you leave the page.

```
.overflow-hidden {
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Attach class on the body in the specific page and remove when you live the page, so it won't affect other pages

```
useEffect(() => {
        document.body.classList.add("overflow-hidden");
        return () => {
            document.body.classList.remove("overflow-hidden");
        };
 }, []);
```

This will simply remove the class from the body when you leave the page.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to [Luke Storry's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63036586/11236319) and [midnightgamer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69370166/11236319) amazing answer. You can use a custom react hook with useEffect instead of having to add `document.body.style.overflow='auto'` in  every page to re-enable scroll.

```
import { useEffect } from 'react'

const useOverFlowHidden = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden'

        return () => {
            document.body.style.overflow = 'auto' // cleanup or run on page unmount
        }
    }, [])
}

export default useOverFlowHidden
```

Usage:

```
const Page = () => {
    useOverFlowHidden(); // use on pages you want to disable overflow/scroll
    return <></>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use [body-scroll-lock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-scroll-lock) npm package:

```
import {disableBodyScroll,enableBodyScroll,clearAllBodyScrollLocks} from "body-scroll-lock"

const YourPage=(props)=>{
     const ref=useRef(null)

     useEffect(() => {
         if (ref.current) {
             // you might add a condition to lock the scroll
             if (conditionIsTrue) {
                   disableBodyScroll(ref.current)
             } else {
             enableBodyScroll(ref.current)
                }
             }
             return () => {
                  clearAllBodyScrollLocks()
                   }    
      },[addDependencyHere])         

     return(
       <div ref={ref}>
       ....
       </>
     )
}
```

- from the above npm package's documentation, you can also use this approach with vanilla js. It is not recommended to access `document` object in react.js directly

  ```
     document.body.ontouchmove = (e) => { 
         e.preventDefault(); 
         return false;
  ```
- on touch screen devices you can set this css class conditionally to prevent scrolling

  ```
  touch-action:none
  ```